# Show/ Hide table rows based on dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, html-table, hide, rows, show

I have a date selector for years 2012 & 2013. Based on the selection I want to display only rows with certain classes. Can someone please show me where I am going wrong?

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".yr12 td").hide();

$('#selectYr').change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == yr12) {
         $('.yr12 td').show();
         $('.yr13 td').hide();
    } else {
        $('.yr12 td').hide();
         $('.yr13 td').show();
    }
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<select id="selectYr">
    <option value="yr13">2013</option>
     <option value="yr12">2012</option>
   </select>
<br><br>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>
<tr class="yr13">
<td>February 2013 </td>
<td>Description 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="yr13">January 2013</td>
<td>Description 2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="yr12">
<td>November 2012</td>
<td>Description 3</td>
</tr>
<tr class="yr12">
<td>December 2012</td>
<td>Description 4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the quotes around your string:

```
if (val == 'yr12') { }
//         ^    ^
```

Comment: o.mi.gosh. Hours lost due to missing quotes. I Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare val to another variable called yr12 instead of comparing to the value 'yr 12'

Here is the correct code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $(".yr12 td").hide();

                $('#selectYr').change(function () {
                    var val = $(this).val();
                    if (val == 'yr12') {
                         $('.yr12 td').show();
                         $('.yr13 td').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('.yr12 td').hide();
                         $('.yr13 td').show();
                    }
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

two things..

1 ->

```
 <tr>
<td class="yr13">January 2013</td>
```

should be

```
<tr class="yr13">
<td>January 2013</td>
```

2-->

```
if (val == "yr12") {
```